# Size of random sample from Normal distribution needed and general use of the Central Limit Theorem

Tags: probability, normal-distribution, sampling, central-limit-theorem

> How large a random sample should be taken from a normal distribution
>   in order for the probability to be at least $0.99$ that the sample
>   mean will be within one standard deviation of the mean of the
>   distribution?

What I have initially done which I think is not valid:

Let $\bar X=\sum^n_{i=1}X_i$ for $X_i\sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$ from our sample.

By the Central Limit theorem $\frac{S_n-n\mu}{\sigma \sqrt{n}} \sim Z$ where $Z$ is the standard normal distribution and $S_n=\sum_iX_i$.

So for large enough $n$ $\bar X=\frac{S_n}n \sim \frac{Z\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}+\mu$

Then approximately $\mathbb P(|\bar X-\mu|<\sigma)=\mathbb P(|\frac{Z\sigma}{\sqrt{n}}|)<\sigma=\mathbb P(|Z|<\sqrt{n})$ and it gives that $\mathbb P(Z<2.58)=0.995$ so $\sqrt{n}>2.58$ will do so $n=9$ but this is surely too small an $n$ for the Central Limit theorem to have been used in the first place.

Is this the correct approach or completely wrong? I feel like from the context of the question the Central Limit theorem should be used somewhere but almost certainly I have not used it correctly.

Any help is appreciated, thanks.

Comment: The CLT is not needed, note that sums of normal distributions are normally distributed.

Comment: Oh thanks, is this obvious?

Comment: It is a well known fact, but perhaps you haven't studied it yet. See for example https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_normally_distributed_random_variables.

Comment: Thanks, yes I have not seen this before